# ¿Cómo le hago para que Java me marque error al usar una clase específica en el código a probar?

Tags: java, junit, pruebas-unitarias

Estoy haciendo un código que servirá de ejericio en el sitio de ejercicios de programación llamado [Codewars](http://www.codewars.com/r/vf5AJA).

De momento llevo esto:

```
package com.codewars.suuuzi;

import org.junit.Test;

import java.math.BigInteger;
import java.util.Random;

import static com.codewars.suuuzi.MultipleOf11.eleven;
import static org.junit.Assert.*;

public class MultipleOf11Test {

    @Test(timeout=50)
    public void basicTests() {
        assertTrue(eleven("11"));
        assertFalse(eleven("3800"));
        assertTrue(eleven("323455693"));
        assertTrue(eleven("30800"));
        assertFalse(eleven("654986546516"));
        assertTrue(eleven("22"));
    }

    @Test(timeout=50)
    public void advancedTests() {
        assertTrue(eleven("112233"));
        assertFalse(eleven("112233456"));
        assertTrue(eleven("11"));
        assertTrue(eleven("22"));
        assertFalse(eleven("3800"));
        assertTrue(eleven("323455693"));
        assertTrue(eleven("30800"));
        assertFalse(eleven("654986546516"));
        assertFalse(eleven("6549865989546546544564698566546546846516546548946545646546546516"));
        assertFalse(eleven("6549865989546546544564698566546546846516546548946545646546546516654986598954654654456469856654654684651654654894654564654654651665498659895465465445646985665465468465165465489465456465465465166549865989546546544564698566546546846516546548946545646546546516"));
        assertTrue(eleven("112233445566778899"));
        assertTrue(eleven("0000000011"));
        assertTrue(eleven("14927"));
        assertTrue(eleven("1727"));
    }

    private boolean sample(String input) {
        String[] charray = input.split("");
        long sum = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < charray.length; i++) {
            if (i % 2 == 0) {
                sum -= Integer.parseInt(charray[i]);
            } else {
                sum += Integer.parseInt(charray[i]);
            }
        }
        return (sum % 11 == 0);
    }

    @Test(timeout=228)
    public void random() {
        Random r = new Random();
        for (int i = 0; i < 240; i++) {
            BigInteger bi = new BigInteger(2345, r);
            // System.out.println(bi.toString());
            assertEquals(sample(bi.toString()), MultipleOf11.eleven(bi.toString()));
        }
    }
}
```

Como podrán ver, en las pruebas unitarias le puse un límite de tiempo muy esricto para evitar que alguien meta una solución que use `BigInteger`, pero no estoy seguro de que sea suficiente.

¿De qué manera podría modificar mi prueba unitaria para que de alguna manera me marque error cuando alquien mande una solución que tenga `BigInteger` en su código?

Ojo, que **marque error o algo** si el código a probar tiene un `BigInteger`.

Comment: Dos cosas. 1) Los errorres de compilación ocurren cuando el compilador no puede interpretar el código (casi siempre problemas de sintaxis), 2) ¿Lo que quieres es que a las pruebas no les puedas meter un BigDecimal o que el método no permita que la entrada sean valores muy grandes?

Comment: 1) Codewars compila en tiempo de ejecución usando groovy. 2.1) sí, 2.2)no